# Contradiction between emmeans and t.test in R

Tags: regression, t-test, interaction, lsmeans

I am analyzing two within-subject categorical variables (Factor A and Factor B) in R. Using linear mixed effects, I got a significant interaction. When I start to analyze the simple effect, I firstly used `t.test`, and then used the `emmeans` package. However, I got different results. I don't know which one I should trust. Particularly, I want to compare B1 and B2 on the level of A1.
The following is the code I have in R:

```r
emm1 = emmeans(model, ~ A * B)
emm1
pairs(emm1, simple = "B")
```

Results:

```r
structure = A1:
   contrast estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
   B1 - B2     0.451 0.140 395   3.230  0.0013
```

For the `t.test`, I firstly subset the data, and run the `t.test`:

```r
datasubset = data[data$A == "A1", ]
datasub.t=t.test(dv~ B, data= datasubset)
```

Results:

```r
t = 1.8013, df = 188.59, p-value = 0.07325
```

So I got different results, and which one should I trust? Or which step that might be incorrect in the code leads to the different results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You said your conditions are within-subject but you did an independent samples t-test. If you do a paired t-test (i.e., setting `paired = TRUE` in the call to `t.test()`), the results will be closer, but still not the same. This is because your repeated measures ANOVA (what I assume you did, but you didn't show the code for it) uses the residual sums of squares across all conditions, whereas the t-test only uses the data from the slice you selected. You should use `emmeans` and not the t-test if you want accurate results.

EDIT given comments: Because your model has two random effects, a t-test, paired or otherwise, is not appropriate to test your slice hypothesis. Again, `emmeans` was specifically designed to test these hypotheses, so use it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I forgot the command `paired=T`.  The model I used is linear mixed effect, and the code is like the following：`data=lmerTest::lmer (dv~factorA*factorB + (1|subject)+(1|item), data = data_, REML=FALSE)`   I am not sure which one I should use if I want to test the simple effect, the `t.test` or the `emmeans` command? What I did is to subset the data and use the `t.test`. And the alternative that I did is to use the `emmeans` based on the linear mixed effect mode. Thank you so much for your answer in advance.

Comment: Hi Noah, by the way, I have another question concerning the format of the data. After subsetting the data, the data is still long format. Is it the appropriate format to perform a paired-t in R? Because usually in SPSS I split the two levels of a variable into two columns when performing a paired-t test. I am new in this area, and there are many things that I am not sure of. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: As I say in my answer, do not use `t.test()`.

Comment: I see! Thanks for your comments! Those are very helpful!